# How to use c8 to generate code coverage of a node micro service running inside a docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm, code-coverage

What I have is a nodejs micro service running inside a docker. What I want is to generate code coverage report of it when BDD tests are run on it.

To generate code coverage reports, I know [c8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c8) can be used. But the problem I am facing is that `c8` needs the node to finish its execution - normal/crash. Since it is a microservice, node never finishes execution after BDD execution.

If I stop the container (`docker stop` or `Ctrl + C` in foreground mode), container exits immediately before `c8` produces it report(I am not sure about this, I am assume it is so).

What can I do in this scenario?

Comment: _NOT AN ANSWER_ As far as I know c8 will not handle sigints. If you pass in a process.exit() somewhere after you've called your endpoints (keep track of state in your server code and then call exit when all responses have been sent -- obviously not ideal but it may be the only way right now) it'll generate the report properly and give you what you expect. I don't know if this will be updated as Istanbul was able to do this if given the --handle-sigint flag and nyc following does it automatically. For the meantime, I suggest you leave an issue under the repo.

Comment: process.exit() does not help either. The report is not generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get `c8` to work for me. But I was able to get [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) to generate code coverage report inside a docker.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can run inside the Dockerfile:

`RUN npx c8 --check-coverage --lines $COVERAGE_VALUE --per-file --temp-directory .c8 yarn run test && npx c8 report --temp-directory .c8 -o out -r text -r cobertura -r html -r text-summary`